# Force iOS interface orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I can change the rotation through several tricks (e.g calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:rotation forKey:@"orientation"];`, or presenting a `UIViewController` with the wanted rotation methods overriden, and dismissing it shortly after).

**The issue is**, when I disable the rotation lock on the phone, and rotate the phone to the wanted rotation, in a `UIViewController` where it isn't supported, but than move to a `UIViewController` (via a pop) where this rotation is supported, the rotation is not applied correctly.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand what you're asking and I've faced this problem before. I solved with putting this in the view controller that's getting popped:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice]performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:) withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)];
    }
}
```